# Spring Batch - Merge each Chunk Item into a Single List in Custom Item Writer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a custom item writer to write to XLSX using JasperReports. My problem is since the data is passed by chunk item, the file is just overwritten by the last chunk item. How can I combine every item into a single list and pass the list to the JasperReports method? Or do you have any other approach in mind to do this.

```
public class CustomerReportWriter implements ItemWriter<Customer> {

    @Autowired
    GenerateReportService generateReportService;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Customer> list) throws Exception {
        // Merge List?
        generateReportService.jasperReport(list);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your `generateReportService` support appending items to the report or does it requires all items at once?

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, it requires all at once. It cannot append.

Comment: In this case, the chunk processing model is probably not the best option. If all your items can hold in memory, you can append them in a shared collection inside the writer and generate the report from that collection in a `StepExecutionListener#afterStep` method.